# system administrator account

Tags: windows-xp

I want to run sql server 2005 application in administrator account.but it is asking for password for log in..I dont know the password.Am working on other system..Is there any possibilities to run my application without password or any other options..pl help me out.

thanks.

Comment: I can't in good faith answer this question because it is such a very mistaken, very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You need to speak to the owner/administrator of the system you intend to run this code on - there's no technical or moral way around it.